# Dataframe with two index columns - reset to one index column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame `df1` that looks like:

```
                 col2  col3
date       dept            
2020-05-07 A       29    21
2020-05-08 B       56    12
2020-05-09 C       82    15
2020-05-10 D       13     9
2020-05-11 E       35    13
2020-05-12 F       53    87
2020-05-13 G       25     9
2020-05-14 H       23    63
```

the data-frame has two index columns (`date` and `dept`).  How can I change the data-frame so that it is only indexed by `date`?  So my desired output looks like:

```
           dept  col2  col3
date                   
2020-05-07    A    29    21
2020-05-08    B    56    12
2020-05-09    C    82    15
2020-05-10    D    13     9
2020-05-11    E    35    13
2020-05-12    F    53    87
2020-05-13    G    25     9
2020-05-14    H    23    63
```

I have tried to use:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index('date')
```

without success.

Answer (score 1):

Here is necessary select column(s) or position(s) for converting to columns:

```
#convert dept to columns
df1 = df1.reset_index(level='dept')
#convert date to columns
#df1 = df1.reset_index('date')
```

Or:

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(level=1)
```